# Setting an internal variable of an explicitly linked DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I am loading a DLL explicitly with `LoadLibrary` and use `GetProcAddress` to load a function from it. So far so good. The following variable is defined in the header file of the DLL (readline.h):

```
READLINE_DLL_IMPEXP FILE *rl_outstream;
```

This variable is used internally by the DLL, which is why I have to change it "inside the DLL". I am new to c++ and couldn't find a way to set this variable in my parent cpp file. This is what I tried:

```
hDLL = LoadLibrary("readline.dll");
hDLL.rl_outstream = fopen("outstream.txt","w");
```

which only yields the following error:

```
error C2228: left of '.rl_outstream' must have class/struct/union
type is 'HINSTANCE'
did you intend to use '->' instead?
```

1. How do I set this DLL variable correctly?
2. Where should I have searched to find the solution to my problem?

Comment: And what is your problem? What is your question? Is there any more code? What result would you expect? What result are you getting?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: my post was corrupted, it only contained the first 2 lines because of that. I just edited it to fix that.

Comment: While [the answer here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb975f44-dd2d-462f-8dd4-bf7bb938108d/how-do-i-import-a-variable-that-is-exported-from-unmanaged-dll?forum=csharplanguage) is in C#, it should be easy to translate it to C++. And I found it by going to my favorite search engine and searched for "use getprocaddress to get a variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set a variable inside the DLL. You need to export this variable. Consider the following example:

We have this DLL:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

FILE *rl_outstream;

void
do_something()
{
  assert(rl_outstream);

  fputs("HELLO", rl_outstream);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

where there is an exported variable named `rl_outstream`, you can set its value like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE **rl_outstream;
  void (*do_something)(void);
  HMODULE hModule;

  hModule = LoadLibraryW(L"./lib.dll");
  assert(hModule);

  rl_outstream = (FILE **) GetProcAddress(hModule, "rl_outstream");
  assert(rl_outstream);

  do_something = (void(*)(void)) GetProcAddress(hModule, "do_something");
  assert(do_something);


  *rl_outstream = fopen("out.txt", "w");
  do_something();
  fclose(*rl_outstream);

  FreeLibrary(hModule);
  return 0;
}
```

after compiling and executing `test.exe`:

```
>g++ -Wall lib.cpp -shared -o lib.dll
>g++ -Wall test.cpp -o test.exe
>test.exe
>type out.txt
HELLO
>
```

Comment: I was succesful applying this concept to my problem! But I am wondering why I need to use double pointers for the GetProcAdress() call. I tried removing all double pointers, but it didn't work then anymore. Can you elaborate on that or provide a link to this concept in general? Is there a reason why you used g++ here? I tried msvc's 2013 cl.exe as well, but my program crashed at some point (loading the DLL's function, which uses rl_outstream), while the g++ compiled variant works nicely.

Comment: `GetProcAddress` will return a pointer to the symbol `rl_outstream`, which is a pointer itself, thus you expect pointer to pointer, if `rl_outstream` was, for example, `int` will you expect `int *` only. With MSVC, you need to explicit export the symbol using `__declspec(dllexport)` before `rl_outstream` and `do_something`, and compile with `cl /MD test.cpp`, `cl /MD /LD lib.cpp msvcrt.lib /link /out:lib.dll`.